# Undefined variable errors with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database that has columns such MyPrice, MyStock, etc.
And several rows for each product - apple, peach, etc.

I'm trying to pull data about the price/stock status of several items using the following code, but I get erros such as:

`Notice: Undefined variable: sql on line 11`

`Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query on line 11`

`Notice: Undefined variable: prices on line 45`

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 45`

```
$dbhost =   'zzz';
$dbuser =   'zzz'; 
$dbpwd  =   'zzz'; 
$dbname =   'zzz';

$conn = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );                
$res = $conn->query( $sql );

$item1 = "apple";
$item2 = "peach";

$items=array( $item1, $item2 );
$sql='select * from products where `Name` in ("'.implode('","',$items).'");'; //line 11

if( $res ){

    $i=0;/* counter for dynamic variables */
    $prices=new stdClass;

    while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
        $i++;

        /* Populate an object with details for the product */
        $prices->{ strtolower( $rs->name ) }=(object)array( 'price'=>$rs->MyPrice, 'description'=>$rs->MyDescription, 'stock'=>$rs->MyStock );

    }
}   
?>  

echo 'Apple:'.$prices->apple->price . '<br />'; //line 45
echo 'Peach:'.$prices->peach->stock . '<br />';
```

What is causing the problems?

Comment: $sql = ($conn, "select * from products where `Name` in ("'.implode('","',$items).'");");

Comment: Just a note, even when you post your entire code(which this is NOT), you have to show us WHERE LINE X IS... We shouldn't have to start counting lines to find the error... Adding something like `// line 20` is enough.

Comment: @FirstOne ok edit been made

Comment: @ChrisG your line results in a PHP syntax error

Comment: Sry, it should be: $sql="$conn, (select * from products where `Name` in ("'.$item_text.'"))";

Comment: you actually should get the first error in line 7, not in 11. You're sure that line-numbers are correct and match that posted code? Here's the error: `$res=$conn->query($sql);` - you haven't defined sql before that

Comment: @Jeff thanks, I think this resolves it

Comment: if your code is successful debugged, you might want to pick one of the answers to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've debugged your code according to the errors you've got.
Anyway, the messeges should lead you to the solution by your self,
especially if they are as clear and obvious.
If you always get your code debugged by someone else you won't learn anything.

```
<?php

$dbhost =   'zzz';
$dbuser =   'zzz'; 
$dbpwd  =   'zzz'; 
$dbname =   'zzz';

$conn = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );                


$item1 = "apple";
$item2 = "peach";

$items=array( $item1, $item2 );
$sql='select * from products where `Name` in ("'.implode('","',$items).'");';

// here's the first two errors.
// Notice: Undefined variable: sql on line 11
// Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query on line 11
// You tried to query the db without defining $sql first (lines were mixed up) -> 
$res = $conn->query( $sql );

if ($res) {
    $prices=new stdClass();
    $i=0; /* counter for dynamic variables */
    while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
        $i++;

        /* Populate an object with details for the product */
        $prices->{ strtolower( $rs->name ) }=(object)array( 'price'=>$rs->MyPrice, 'description'=>$rs->MyDescription, 'stock'=>$rs->MyStock );

    }
    // here's 3rd and 4th error:
    // Notice: Undefined variable: prices on line 45
    // only output if you got values, so put the output into if-condition
    echo 'Apple:'.$prices->apple->price . '<br />';
    echo 'Peach:'.$prices->peach->stock . '<br />';
} else {
    // database didn't return anything, so tell the user or something with that information.
    echo 'no data found or an error occured<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move $res=$conn->query($sql);
To line 12

Also remove the end
?>
And place at end off file

Comment: Changed the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

This is your first offender:

```
$sql='select * from products where `Name` in ("'.implode('","',$items).'");';
```

you should implode $items prior to trying to concatenating it into an sql statement.

Something like:

```
$item_text = implode('","',$items);
$sql='select * from products where `Name` in ("'.$item_text.'");';
```

Honestly, this code is a bit of a mess. You should use either PDO or mysql not both and clean this up.

Comment: That's just the first I saw, once you resolve the others, I'm sure it would come up.

Comment: You are querying data before you define it. $sql is not defined when you try to query the database
$res = $conn->query( $sql );
then you define it a few lines later
$sql='select * from products where `Name` in ("'.implode('","',$items).'");';

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start

```
$dbhost =   'zzz';
$dbuser =   'zzz'; 
$dbpwd  =   'zzz'; 
$dbname =   'zzz';

$conn = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );                

$item1 = "apple";
$item2 = "peach";

$items=array( $item1, $item2 );
$item_text = implode('","',$items);
$sql='select * from products where `Name` in ("'.$item_text.'");'; //line 11

$res = $conn->query( $sql );

if( $res ){

    $i=0;/* counter for dynamic variables */
    $prices=new stdClass;

    while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
        $i++;

        /* Populate an object with details for the product */
        $prices->{ strtolower( $rs->name ) }=(object)array( 'price'=>$rs->MyPrice, 'description'=>$rs->MyDescription, 'stock'=>$rs->MyStock );

    }
}   


echo 'Apple:'.$prices->apple->price . '<br />'; //line 45
echo 'Peach:'.$prices->peach->stock . '<br />';

?>
```

Comment: the echo's at the end need to go first inside php-tag, second inside if($res) (otherwise $price could be undefined)

Comment: true, I can't believe I didn't see that.